# When I include graphics , I get a very bad quality due to scaling?

Tags: graphics

When I use `scale=0.3` I get a low quality images, Is this normal ? is there a way to avoid that ?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A m a title}

       \begin{figure}[hT]
       \includegraphics[scale=0.360]{imgs/classical.png}
     \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this depends on the quality of the original figure file as well, I would say. `png` is no vector graphics format, so scaling is always an issue then

Comment: so it is better that I export my images in `svg` ?

Comment: `.png` files are bitmaps, and don't scale well.  if you can get a vector graphics file, that would be preferable.  otherwise, if there is any way you can get the file directly at the size you want to use it, that would give much better results.  (but it would still scale poorly for someone changing the magnification on a `.pdf` file while viewing it.)

Comment: @Ojiryx: No, use `.pdf` or `.eps` and convert to `.pdf` then, but see barbara beeton's comment as well

Comment: Define low quality, bitmap is usually not a problem when you scale down from a good quality starting point. So if your png is bad quality to begin with...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.png` files are bitmaps, and don't scale well.  if you can get a vector graphics file, that would be preferable.

as suggested by christian hupfer,
a `.pdf` file (or `.eps` file converted to `pdf`) is best, since it is in
the same format as the output file you are producing.

if you *must* use a bitmap file, try to get the file at exactly
the size you intend to use it; that would give much better results.
(but it would still scale poorly for someone changing the magnification
on a `.pdf` file while viewing it.)

Comment: I did some comparison of graphics scaling between Microsoft Word and LaTeX. It is almost identical and slightly better in LaTeX. The Word version is slightly (but almost not) more blurry and the contrast is definitely better in LaTeX.